# How to change window.location.href according to return value?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, asynchronous, href

I use this in render function

```
    @observable private redirectUrl: string = null;

    public async componentWillMount() {
        this.redirectUrl = await this.getRedirectUrl();
    }

    public render() {
        if (this.redirectUrl) {
            window.location.href = this.redirectUrl;
            return null;
    }
```

where redirectUrl is observable and get by a async function. But it is not working in componentWillMount function. I think the reason is that it is get by async.

How to solve this?

Comment: `async` function will return a `Promise`, not the actual value. Perhaps, that's the reason why it's not working. Things would be much more clear if you post all relevant code.

Comment: Are you sure you want to assign a value to the global location object? I'm thinking you need to pragmatically navigate to the redirect url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `async` function will return a promise, you can do something like following,

```
async componentWillMount () {
    await anotherAsyncFunction()
    window.location.href = this.redirectUrl
}
```

Hope will work.

Comment: Thank you, it works. I add assign to window.location.href in the async function.